# How to stream binary data into a PostgreSQL BYTEA column using the Golang lib/pq API?

Tags: postgresql, go, pq

I'd like to insert some binary data into a BYTEA column,

How would I go about streaming the contents of somefile.tar.gz into a table with a BYTEA column?

Is it possible to stream to/from postgres from/to golang?

Comment: Did you have a look at the documentation of the packages? Like mentioned, use `[]byte` for `bytea` columns in [pq](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#hdr-Data_Types). [sqlx examples](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx#usage) of inserting data.

Answer (score 1):

If one would be willing to switch to `github.com/jackc/pgx`, [Large Objects](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v4#LargeObjects) (PostgreSQL [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/largeobjects.html)) can be streamed. The `pgx.LargeObject` type implements:

> ```
> io.Writer
> io.Reader
> io.Seeker
> io.Closer
> ```

Large Objects are stored in a system table, there is no Large Object type which can be used in a column of a table. Large Objects are referenced by their [object identifier](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/datatype-oid.html). So a separate table needs to be maintained with file metadata and `oid` mapping.

Example program:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4"
)

const (
    // files table maps Large Object oid to file names
    createFileTable = `CREATE TABLE files (
        id oid primary key,
        name varchar,
        unique(name)
    );`
)

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.TODO(), time.Minute)
    defer cancel()

    conn, err := pgx.Connect(ctx, "user=postgres host=/run/postgresql dbname=postgres")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close(ctx)

    if _, err = conn.Exec(ctx, createFileTable); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    written, err := storeFile(ctx, conn, "somefile.bin")
    log.Printf("storeFile written: %d", written)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    read, err := loadFile(ctx, conn, "somefile.bin")
    log.Printf("loadFile read: %d", read)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

// storeFile as Large Object in the database.
// The resulting object identifier is stored along with the file name in the files table.
// The amount of written bytes and an erorr is returned, if one occured.
func storeFile(ctx context.Context, conn *pgx.Conn, name string) (written int64, err error) {
    file, err := os.Open(name)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    // LargeObjects can only operate on an active TX
    tx, err := conn.Begin(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    defer tx.Rollback(ctx)

    lobs := tx.LargeObjects()

    // Create a new Large Object.
    // We pass 0, so the DB can pick an available oid for us.
    oid, err := lobs.Create(ctx, 0)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    // record the oid and filename in the files table
    _, err = tx.Exec(ctx, "INSERT INTO files (id, name) VALUES ($1, $2)", oid, name)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    // Open the new Object for writing.
    obj, err := lobs.Open(ctx, oid, pgx.LargeObjectModeWrite)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    // Copy the file stream to the Large Object stream
    written, err = io.Copy(obj, file)
    if err != nil {
        return written, err
    }

    err = tx.Commit(ctx)
    return written, err
}

// loadFile loads the file identified by name as Large Object
// and writes the contents to a local file by the same name.
// The amount of bytes read or an error is returned.
func loadFile(ctx context.Context, conn *pgx.Conn, name string) (read int64, err error) {
    tx, err := conn.Begin(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    defer tx.Rollback(ctx)

    var oid uint32
    err = conn.QueryRow(ctx, "SELECT id FROM files WHERE name = $1", name).Scan(&oid)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    file, err := os.Create(name)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    lobs := tx.LargeObjects()
    obj, err := lobs.Open(ctx, oid, pgx.LargeObjectModeRead)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    return io.Copy(file, obj)
}
```